# Only arrays and iterables are allowed at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to get the data from the api to display on the component.html on Angular. But i'm stuck at this problem

So it supposed to show the totalDeaths from the API which is "238569".

ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '238569'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let deaths of tDeaths"
  [value]="deaths">
  {{ deaths }}
</li>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoronaService } from '../corona.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-covid',
  templateUrl: './covid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./covid.component.css']
})
export class CovidComponent implements OnInit {
  public tDeaths:any = [];
  constructor(private coronaService : CoronaService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.coronaService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);

        this.tDeaths = data.Global.TotalDeaths;
      });
  }  
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoronaService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
    });
}

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to iterate a number. You need to either provide an array to *ngFor (maybe to map an object to an array with Object.keys/Object.values) or don't use ngFor if the output value is not supposed to be an array in the first place.

Comment: I checked the data at https://api.covid19api.com/summary and it seems like you're trying to render a list from a number, which makes no sense, so maybe you wanted to just render the number as single element like that <span>{{ tDeaths }}</span>

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the data to your tDeaths in the OnInit. Since you declared it as an array.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.coronaService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);

        this.tDeaths.push(data.Global.TotalDeaths);
        return this.tDeaths
      });
  }
```